# Usar o TChromium para fazer um navegador

Tags: delphi, chromium

Quero usar o *TChromium* para fazer um navegador com o *Delphi*. Mas não estou conseguindo acessar qualquer página com ele.
Já usei os comandos:

```
Chromium1.Load('www.terra.com.br');
```

Também:

```
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('www.terra.com.br');
```

E não vai!!

Alguém sabe como usar esse componente?

Comment: Percebi que quando o site abre no protocolo *https* ocorre o problema.  No protocolo *http*, os sites abrem normalmente. Chega a ser até engraçado, porque o **Bing** eu consigo abrir, mas o **Google** não abre por ser *https*

Comment: Tem como usar o novo webview2 da Microsoft ( Edge )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina a propriedade `DefaultURL` com o caminho que desejas abrir com página inicial.

Já para carregamento de outras páginas use:

De `Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('www.google.com.br);`

Para `Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('https://www.google.com.br/);`

Ou seja, tem que usar o caminho absoluto para ele carregar!

Obs: O Método `LoadString` serve para você definir uma página inicial Fixa que você criou (seu próprio html).

Usei o `Delphi Chromium Embedded 3` para montar essa resposta.

Comment: Uma dúvida: Se o *browser* só funciona se houver o caminho absoluto, complica... Porque o usuário não vai digitar o caminho absoluto. Digo isso no caso de usar o *browser* como se fosse um navegador. E testei conforme você postou, mas ainda não funcionou

Comment: Eis a questão, todo Navegador ao iniciar a navegação testa o https (caso não adicionado), em um resultado negativo ele navegano http. Sobre você testar e não funcionar o que postei, certifique-se copiou as DLL corretas para usar o navegador Delphi Chromium Embedded 3